# How to get the aliased type of a type alias in scala runtime?

Tags: scala, reflection, types, scala-reflect, scala-2.12

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

object Main {

  final type INeedDetails = (Int, String, Unit, Nothing, Float)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = println {
    typeTag[INeedDetails]
  }

}
```

The snippet above will prnint `TypeTag[Main.INeedDetails]`. Is there any way to extract the complete `(Int, String, Unit, Nothing, Float)` tuple information from this `TypeTag`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `dealias` the type from the tag:

```
scala> type INeedDetails = (Int, String, Unit, Nothing, Float)
defined type alias INeedDetails

scala> typeTag[INeedDetails].tpe
res1: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = INeedDetails

scala> typeTag[INeedDetails].tpe.dealias
res2: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = (scala.Int, String, scala.Unit, scala.Nothing, scala.Float)
```